# How to access $auth from Nuxt middleware?

Tags: nuxt.js

How to access $auth from a middleware with Nuxt ?

```js
export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
  console.log(store.state.foo)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nuxtjs Auth module not working in the middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64444811/nuxtjs-auth-module-not-working-in-the-middleware)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one may work too I guess.

```js
export default function ({ $auth })
```

Answer (score 0):

This works but there might be a better answer.

```js
export default function (context) {
  if (context.$auth.user.foo) {
    context.redirect('/bar')
  }
}
```